# Ideapad y480 - BIOS, secure boot

Tags: bios

Trying to disable secure boot to run windows 8 on my dual boot ubuntu/win8 ideapad(shows some secure boot errors when i try to run win8), and I can, but it's never actually disabled(this is the bios):

```
SECURE BOOT [DISABLED]
SECURE BOOT STATUS ENABLED
```

I set it to disabled but the status is always enabled and thus I can't access some files. How can I fix this? Or is it not necessary to turn off secure boot for dual boot?

Comment: Which files can't you access?

Comment: probably worded that wrong, from the ubuntu os selection menu the windows entries don't work - "can't find drivemap", etc., already googled that but i thought fixing this first would be better

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue that you can't boot to Windows directly from the GRUB2 menu when Secure Boot is enabled.

In order to boot to Windows, you'll need to go to the startup menu (I think it's <kbd>F12</kbd> on Lenovo machines) and select "Windows Bootloader" from the device list.

Comment: just got "windows boot failed"

Comment: Interesting. Did it give you any option to try to do an automatic repair or anything?

Comment: don't think so...